# Strange count of lines on Word table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am creating a VBA script and when I want to count the number of lines between two words, a strange thing is happened.

When between two word exist a table, the count of lines into the table is wrong, i.e, the first row is in the line 23, second in the line 17, third in the line 23 and fourth in the line 18.

[image][image][image][image]

I use this code:

```
Sub delete() 'Eliminar los apartados que no aplican

    Dim intCurrentLine, toLine, aux As String

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = "[word1]"
        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True, Format:=True) = True
            Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=("[word1]")
            intCurrentLine = Selection.Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
            Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
            Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=("[word2]")
            toLine = Selection.Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
            Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=("[word1]")
            Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1

            'Contar paginas, si la pagina si hay mas de una pagina, se recorre la pagina para contar y sumar las lineas.

            If toLine > intCurrentLine Then
                Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=toLine - intCurrentLine + 1, Extend:=wdExtend
            Else
                Selection.GoToNext (wdGoToPage)
                Selection.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
                aux = Selection.Range.Information(wdFirstCharacter)
                Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
                Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=("[word1]")
                Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
                Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=aux - intCurrentLine + toLine + 1, Extend:=wdExtend
            End If
            Selection.delete
            intCurrentLine = 0
            fromLine = 0
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

What is the problem? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you can add an illustration to make this easier to understand 

Comment: Post has been updated

Comment: Sorry those images are confusing - you say count the number of lines between 2 words... there are 4 images? It does not show where you start and stop counting.  Please also explain what you mean by lines... paragraphs? Please post some code so we can help you properly :-)

Comment: Post has been updated. The problem is not in the words, the problem is located on the table, in the count of the table rows.

Comment: Oh, Ok... but HOW are you getting the result? VBA? Post your code or provide some steps to reproduce 

Comment: I need the line count for know how many lines are between two words. When I know count of lines, I can select all between this two words and delete it. But when some table is in the middle, the count is wrong and the VBA code select more lines than it should.

Comment: Yes... but please share HOW are you getting the count now??

Comment: I added in the post the code used to lines count

Comment: I can't reproduce it at all, can you share a test document with a table the relevant code and dummy text?

Comment: You have to create a document with a text and add words "word1" and "word2", in this order.

Comment: Ok... well there are a few problems with the code you submitted, but I suspect it is only part of the code. I think your problem comes from how you use Selection but unless I see more of the code I can not really tell :-/

Comment: I added the complite code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158307/discussion-between-slowlearner-and-iratzar-carrasson-bores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of your requirements, but have modified your code - please try this and let me know if it works for you:

```
Sub delete()
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim rngEnd As Range
    Dim rngDelete As Range

    Dim wordOne As String
    wordOne = "word1"
    Dim wordTwo As String
    wordTwo = "word2"

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = wordOne
        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True, Format:=True) = True

            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

            Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=(wordOne)
            Set rngStart = Selection.Range
            ' At this point the selection = the 'found text'    
            Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd ' set range to end of found text
            Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=(wordTwo)
            Set rngEnd = Selection.Range


            Set rngDelete = rngStart.Duplicate
            'rngDelete.Collapse wdCollapseEnd ' Keep wordOne
            rngDelete.Collapse wdCollapseStart ' Delete wordOne
            'rngDelete.End = rngEnd.Start ' Keep wordTwo
            rngDelete.End = rngEnd.End ' Delete wordTwo 
            rngDelete.Text = " " ' replace rngDelete Text with a space
            'rngDelete.Text = vbNullString ' replace rngDelete Text with nothing
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note:**

I added a test that words 1 & 2 are on the same page, but really not sure if this is required.

Comment: It is correct but the words didn't are deleted. What can I do to delete it?

Comment: Ok the original answer is updated, I did it like that because you said: "I want to delete all between word1 and word2." English is tricky, instead of saying *between word1 and word2* you meant *from word1 to word2* ;-0 hope it helps

Comment: I added `Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory` because if eliminated section is big, it can be happen that the next "wordOne" is before the selection section, so I have to return to the beginning. Another question: Why do you use ´Stop´ in the If sentence, I can delete it, right?

Comment: Rejecting the edit because I don't think it is possible that can happen because my code always starts from the start then finds the first `wordOne` - I can't see how a new wordOne would then be able to appear in front of the original wordOne...

Comment: But... if my solution works for you (or helped a lot) then please accept and up-vote :-)

Comment: In my case, two "wordOne"s weren't undeleted and with the change that I did in your answer, they were deleted. With the _Stop_ in the If sentence, it can be deleted in my opinion. So I think you should edit the code again and do no doubt that I will accept your answer and up-vote for your work.

Comment: Yes, the Stop can be deleted. Strange that the other oneWord weren't deleted... feel free to edit.